# Math & JavaScript | Random chances

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to figure the math behind a pretty known site called [bustabit](https://www.bustabit.com/play).

I can't seem to find the right math behind it since whenever I'm trying the things I come up with the odds seem to always be way different. According to the site you can find the odds here, [calc](https://www.bustabit.com/calculator).

Okay, so basically I'm trying to generate a random number that can go up to unlimited with chances attached to them, if we remove all edged the chance of the number being 200 should be about fifty percent, 300 thirtythree, and 500 about twenty percent.

What I figured out to replicate the system, which in my opinion doesn't really fit the odds.

```
var mainMultiplier = 99;

var numerator = 100;
var denominator = 101;      

var chance = 1;

for(;;){
    var randomInt = random.real(0, 1.0); 

  if(numerator/denominator > randomInt){
    numerator = numerator+1;
    denominator = denominator+1;
    mainMultiplier = mainMultiplier+1;
    chance = chance*(numerator/denominator);
  }else{
    break;
  }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this in a better way?

You can figure out the odds in the calculator that I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: What does it mean "remove all edged"? Do you mean the chance of 200 itself should be about 50 percent, or the chance of being in the first 200? Also, do these chances overlap, because the sum exceeds 100 percent?

Comment: Edges I meant, but the number should be able to get up to for example a million but the chances of that are very slim as you can find if you put in a million on the calculator provided. Chances on reaching 200 are 50 percent and so on, I need to find a good method of generating a number where the chances are as provided in the calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
var number = 100.0 / (1 - Math.random());
```

Generating a million samples like this just now, the relative distribution went like this:

```
100 - 199 : 499817
200 - 299 : 166405
300 - 399 :  83643
400 - 499 :  50002
500 - 599 :  33155
600 - 699 :  23717
700 - 799 :  18030
800 - 899 :  13811
900 - 999 :  11140
```

generated thus:

```
// make array
var a = [];
for (i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i) {
    a.push(100.0 / (1 - Math.random()));
}

// count the distribution
var dist = a.reduce((p, n) => {
    n = 100 * Math.floor(n / 100);
    p[n] = ++p[n] || 1;
    return p;
}, {});
```

Note that numbers below 100 are not generated - deducting 100 from the value (and perhaps adjusting the 100 in the initial dividend) would resolve that.

Comment: Wait, is it really that easy? Can this number go up to unlimited?

Comment: It's implementation dependent, but it should be able to get up into the 10^19 range if the `Math.random` RNG uses the full 53 bits of binary resolution available.

Comment: I'm a sucker at maths but would this also match my description of the chances that I'd like to have? Chances in this case are really important.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens "approximately" - as you can see above I generated numbers in the range 100 - 199 in 499817 out of one million attempts.

Comment: I see that, but the chances of going 101 should be higher then the chance of it generating for example 103 or 141.

Comment: right, and indeed they are.  The point is that the division therein effectively converts the _linear distribution_ of the random variable in the range `[0, 1)` into an _inverse linear_ distribution in the range `[100, ~Inf)`

Comment: I did find another way to do it using crypto's, I'm unsire if it's the correct way of doing it tho. Thanks for the answer tho :)